# How to filter top customer with top product ordered?

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I want to filter top 2 customers with their top 2 products they had ordered over a period.

| Date | Customer | Product | Qty | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/10/2023 | Mike | Apple | 1 | 3.00 |
| 1/10/2023 | Joyce | Apple | 1 | 3.00 |
| 2/10/2023 | Naomi | Orange | 1 | 2.00 |
| 2/10/2023 | Naomi | Apple | 1 | 3.00 |
| 3/10/2023 | Naomi | Orange | 1 | 2.00 |
| 3/10/2023 | Mike | Orange | 1 | 2.00 |
| 4/10/2023 | Naomi | Banana | 1 | 1.00 |
| 4/10/2023 | Mike | Orange | 1 | 2.00 |
| 4/10/2023 | Mike | Grapes | 1 | 1.00 |
| 5/10/2023 | Mike | Orange | 1 | 2.00 |
| 5/10/2023 | Helen | Orange | 1 | 2.00 |

See codes that l have tried

```
 `SELECT 
 TOP 5 O.Customer, O.CustomerId
 FROM Orders O
 JOIN (
 SELECT Customer, TOP 2 Product, Sum(Sales) as Sales
 FROM OrderDetail O2
 GROUP BY Customer, Product
 ORDER BY SUM(OrderDetail.Sales) DESC
 ) O2 ON O2.CustomerId = O.CustomerId
 ORDER BY O.CustomerId
 `
```

Expected output

| Customer | Total Sales | Orange | Apple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Naomi | 9.00 | 6.00 | 3.00 |
| Mike | 7.00 | 4.00 | 3.00 |

Comment: What would be the output if the top 2 customers had _three_ fruits between them?

Comment: My purpose for this is to filter top two fruits between them.

Comment: What if the top 2 customers in terms of total sales only have 1 or 0 fruits in common?

Comment: @stuck, it should still display the top 2 customers with 1 or 0 fruits, but it should not exceed it top two fruits.

Comment: That’s not a very specific requirement. Change all of Naomi’s apple (or orange) sales to banana. What does the output look like? Are there three fruit columns? Impossible to understand the desired outcome based on your description.